# For which values of n is there a graph on n vertices with minimum degree = 2 with no 2-factor?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I'm still kind of new to 2-factors in general, but I know they're a collection of cycles that uses all vertices (so all have degree 2).

I started sketching some examples and found that the complete graphs on 3, 4 and 5 vertices all have 2-factors, you just use the edges on the edge of the graph and get 1 cycle. My intuition says all complete graphs would have a 2-factor, but the question mentions minimum degree, so I don't know how to use that.

Comment: I assume that the $n$ in the title question is supposed to be the number of vertices?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes n is the number of vertices

Answer (score 1):

For $n=5$, the graph with edges $ab,ac,ad,be,ce,de$ has no 2-factors (why?). For any $n>5$ we can find an example from an $n-1$ example  by splitting an edge with a new vertex.

Can you show that $n=4$ always allows a 2-factor?